# Strange bounty auto-accept behavior

Tags: feature-request, bounties

Please take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037805/copy-an-attribute-of-a-property-from-one-instance-to-another-instance-of-a-diffe/3067556#3067556).  The OP placed a bounty on it that expired yesterday.  I was late to the question (as usual) but posted a good answer.  The OP thought so too and accepted the answer.  But was probably not aware of the new rules and never assigned the bounty.  I tried to warn him to no avail.

This morning, I found the bounty auto-assigned.  Marc got it but it is completely unclear to me why his post was selected.  It was neither the accepted answer nor the highest up-voted answer nor the first answer.

It would have been a bit tragic if it would have been awarded to the highest voted answer in this case, but that's another matter.  Please consider that iff the OP was the originator of the bonus *and* accepted an answer then to select that answer to auto-assign the bounty to.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean auto-assigning the *full* bounty amount, or half the amount as auto-awarding currently works?

Comment: Speed cannot matter much to the OP if he's the bounty originator, the answer is always late anyway.  So pick the answer he selected and the award he gave it.  Picking an earlier upvoted post makes little sense to me, he'd would have picked that one instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marc had the highest upvoted answer that was created *after the bounty*.

From the [SO FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

> - If you do not award your bounty within  7 days, the highest voted answer created *after the bounty started* with at least 2 upvotes will be automatically accepted. Half the bounty amount will be awarded to the owner of that answer.

So, both Marc and you answered after the bounty was created, you with 3 votes, he with 4. The OP selected your post as the answer but forgot to award you the bounty. The bounty expired and went to the highest voted answer which was still Marc's.

Comment: Agreed, that looks accurate.  Hope you don't mind me not marking the answer just yet, holding out for a feature change.  Being the slowest gun of the Mid-West, answer marks are my bread and butter.

Comment: I don't need checkmarks, I'm just here to help. Take your time.

Comment: @Hans:  For someone on a bread and butter diet, you [eat quite well](http://stackoverflow.com/users/17034?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top) :-)

Comment: @James, I know you consistently get a *lot* of upvotes.  For a smuck like me, getting rep from marked answers is important to avoid spending too much time at this place.  Call it a personal flaw, apply it as you see fit.  I haven't yet figured out what is wrong with posting a good answer that gets accepted, even if it is not 10 seconds after it gets asked.  I hate to see that get watered down even more.  This is very self-serving, I rarely learn anything insightful from a quicky answer that gets hammered quickly to get the Enlightment badge.

Comment: @Hans:  I meant my comment only in jest; I hope it wasn't taken in some other manner and and if it was I am sorry.  I often think that my answers regularly get more votes than they deserve relative to answers given by people with far greater expertise than I.  Still, I sincerely hope that none of my answers only water down the utility of SO (and if one did, I only hope someone would let me know).  In any case, I know that I'm glad to have had your help in the past and I am thankful for that.

Comment: @James: not at all.  Argh, I'll shut this down, it isn't going anywhere.