# Why didn't I get the bounty?

Tags: support, bounties

This thread had a bounty of 150 on it ...

[How to add statusbar correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268762/how-to-add-statusbar-correctly)

My answer was accepted a day or so before the bounty finished and I note the user has lost the reputation.  On the other hand I never received the bounty.  Why is that?

Comment: support [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54444/add-popup-alert-box-to-choose-bounty-award-when-accepting-the-answer-on-bounty-qu) to improve the situation

Comment: I can't give you your deserved bounty, but I can give you an up vote which is worth what? 10 points?  :)

Comment: Cheers, always nice :)

Comment: I can't get any traction on this thread either: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54977/strange-bounty-auto-accept-behavior

Comment: Ame here for me :( 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363645/update-specfic-column-in-grid-view/3401420#3401420

Shouldn't accepting the answer be enough!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because OP didn't click +150 icon under it, and you don't have +2 upvotes to get half bounty.

Bounty rules [changed](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/), and accepting an answer does not automatically award bounty anymore.

Comment: Ahh ... what a bummer.

Comment: So OP can post bounty to draw attention to their question and then never award it? Guess I'll be doing that for every question I post. +1000 to anyone who answers my question! SIKE.

Comment: @CharlieMartin but as I understand you will lose each time the rep even if you do not award it ?

Answer (score 11):

The implementation has changed a bit to better accommodate careless bounty owners. :)

If ...

- the bounty was started by the question owner
- the question owner accepts an answer *during the bounty period*
- the bounty award period expires without an explicit award

... then we assume the question owner liked your answer when they accepted it, and it gets the full amount of the bounty **at time of bounty expiration**.

Comment: Will this apply retroactively, or only for bounties set henceforth?

Comment: @nhinkle it won't apply retroactively

Comment: Nice one ... so many times people fail to click the bounty award button!

Comment: @Jeff: you might also want to look into the time limit. As I read the comments [on this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259647/mysql-match-against-order-by-relevance-and-column/6305108#6305108), some of the "careless bounty owners" may in fact be users who genuinely tried to grant their bounty on the spot, but couldn't do so because the system wouldn't allow them to, and forgot to do so later.

Comment: @Jeff: So what happens if you set a bounty on someone else's question? Does it get auto awarded to the accepted question even though the OP is not the bounty owner? Or does it not work in this case, with the default rules for half being awarded applied?

Comment: @today it is exactly the same rules as if you are the owner

Comment: Is this true even if the accepted answer had been posted before the bounty was set?

Answer (score 2):

I would probably guess that they only accepted your answer but didn't assign the bounty to you.  And you won't get half the bounty automatically as you need at least 2 up votes