# Bounty information in site FAQs doesn't match the current ruleset

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, faq-update-request

As a [recent question] on SU has revealed, and another [SO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98988/147926) has stumbled upon, it looks like the [site FAQs](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) make no mention of two recent and important changes to the bounty system:

> **[Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68050/a-grace-period-of-one-day-to-award-the-bounty-after-expiration-without-remaining/74037#74037)** [23rd June]
>   I decided it can't hurt to extend the auto-award period 24 hours past the true end of the bounty. So, the question will stop being a bounty question at the original scheduled time but the auto-accept calculations will always occur 24 hours after that.

and

> **[Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55199/why-didnt-i-get-the-bounty/91442#91442)** [16th May]
>   If ...
>
> - the bounty was started by the question owner
> - the question owner accepts an answer *during the bounty period*
> - the bounty award period expires without an explicit award
>
> ... then we assume the question owner liked your answer when they
>   accepted it, and it gets the full amount of the bounty **at time of
>   bounty expiration**.

Can the FAQ please be updated to reflect both of these changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, these sections are both accounted for in the /faq I just checked in.