# Why didn't this answer receive a bounty?

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [A grace period of one day to award the bounty after expiration (without remaining featured, of course)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68050/a-grace-period-of-one-day-to-award-the-bounty-after-expiration-without-remaining)
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596364/tracking-c-lib-public-api-changes/6652570#6652570) is the highest rated answer with at least two upvotes. I'm *pretty sure* I answered it after the bounty was placed. The bounty period has expired and no bounty has come my way.

How can I verify that my memory isn't playing tricks on me? Only the approximate  time of the bounty is evident via "ended 5 hours ago."

Or, does the bounty show up tomorrow, or after some action on the part of the awarder? I gather [from the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) that this is automatic.

Confused.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68050/a-grace-period-of-one-day-to-award-the-bounty-after-expiration-without-remaining/74037#74037

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Duplicating my answer to an [identical question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2940/why-was-bounty-not-awarded) on SU from a few moments ago.

---

Bounties now get a 24hours grace period after they expire in which the person posting the bounty can award it before it is dealt with automatically. After this timer expires, and assuming the person posting the bounty doesn't manually award it, the bounty will follow the automatic award pattern as detailed in the FAQ.

This is quite a new change:

> **[Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68050/a-grace-period-of-one-day-to-award-the-bounty-after-expiration-without-remaining/74037#74037)**
>   due to a lot of <strike>whining</strike> valued community feedback on this issue, I decided it can't hurt to extend the auto-award period 24 hours past the true end of the bounty. So, the question will stop being a bounty question at the original scheduled time but the auto-accept calculations will always occur 24 hours after that.

You are correct that this doesn't seem to be reflected in the FAQ correctly.

Also missing from the FAQ seems to be note that the full bounty will be auto-awarded to the accepted answer (if there is one and the question owner posted the bounty) in preference to the highest scoring answer, also a fairly recent change:

> **[Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55199/why-didnt-i-get-the-bounty/91442#91442)**
>   If ...
>
> - the bounty was started by the question owner
> - the question owner accepts an answer *during the bounty period*
> - the bounty award period expires without an explicit award
>
> ... then we assume the question owner liked your answer when they
>   accepted it, and it gets the full amount of the bounty **at time of
>   bounty expiration**.

---

Also note that I've just raised another question on MSO to get the [FAQ updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98987/bounty-information-in-site-faqs-doesnt-match-current-the-ruleset).

Comment: >_> beat me to it 2/2 times today, all in a matter of moments

Answer (score 1):

It now takes a day before the bounty is automatically awarded, so the user has more time to decide.

Comment: In that case perhaps the FAQ should be clarified. I can't see a wiki-like `[edit]` -- who should I notify?