# What to do against unfair users?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, users

Some days ago, I answered a question. This question had an open bounty, so if the user who asked it marks it as approved should "pay" 50 points. I believe (well, I'm sure) the question is answered and it should be marked as valid, but the user don't do it and the bounty will finish in 2 days. I've asked the user for more info about why he don't mark the question, but he is not responding.

What can I do? Is there any mechanism in Stack Overflow to report this kind of unfair behaviours?

Comment: You are accusing that person of being unfair. Accusing people of being unfair, without strongly supporting your assertion, is not [nice](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette).

Comment: I just say: I asked a question that was open for weeks. I proved that this solution was right. I answered for a related question to this user. And after some days, I asked the user if he had any additional problem but he say nothing. I don't know if this user knows how bounty works. Before I ask this question, I didn't know, I though the bounty points were loosed, but now I know that Stack Overflow system is very good and if there is an unfair user he will have a penalty (I don't know if he is).

Comment: Have you considered that maybe he hasn't been back to the site for a couple of days?

Comment: Yes, he returned the site after my comments

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wait patiently, he still has 2 days to assign the bounty.

If he doesn't, the bounty will be automatically given to the highest voted answer, as long as it has more than 2 up-votes.

From https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount. If there's no answer meeting that criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

Also note that, even if the user doesn't award the bounty, he will have given up the amount of reputation he specified on the bounty.

> In any case, you will always give up the amount of reputation specified in the bounty, so if you start a bounty, be sure to follow up and award your bounty to the best answer!

Answer (score 16):

The bounty on this question is ending in two days.

The OP is *certainly* within his right to wait those two days if another answer comes along that might fit his problem better.

And even if he doesn't accept any answer, some amount will be given to the highest-voted answer (if I remember correctly, didn't follow this too closely).

So I don't really see the problem.

A bounty is **not** a guarantee that **you** will get it if you post an answer (even a correct one).

Comment: There is also an additional 24 hours after the bounty period ends for the user to award to the bounty. See the [Bounty FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) for full details on how the bounty system works.

Answer (score 3):

The user who asked the question has still three days to assign the bounty, but there is nothing that forces the OP to assign a bounty.
In the case the OP doesn't accept any answer, or manually give the bounty, the answer with the higher score will automatically get half of the bounty.

About what can be done for who don't assign the bounty, I don't think there is much that can be done, in the same way there isn't much that can be done for who don't accept any answer for the questions they ask.

Comment: FYI: Answers accepted *during the bounty period* are [automatically given](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55199/why-didnt-i-get-the-bounty/91442#91442) the bounty when it expires if it was put up by the question owner and it's not awarded manually.

Comment: I was contracting myself, between the first part and the part where I say "in the case the OP doesn't accept any answer, or manually give the bounty."