# Bounty Award After Accepted Answer

Tags: discussion, bounties

If my answer is accepted, but the give bounty button is not pressed, when the bounty period expires, do I receive the full bounty?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: It isn't.  Check out http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54977/strange-bounty-auto-accept-behavior

Comment: Well that is annoying. Who thinks if the person who asked the question creates the bounty and accepts an answer, the accepted answer should automatically receive the bounty UNLESS THE PERSON WHO ASKED THE QUESTION UN-CHECKS A CHECKBOX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While bounty wasn't tied to the accepted answer in the past, now as per Jeff's answer it will be awarded if the answer was accepted during the bounty period.  Note that this was never added into the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), so it's double-secret.

Answer (score 11):

The implementation has changed a bit to better accommodate careless bounty owners. :)

If ...

- the bounty was started by the question owner
- the question owner accepts an answer *during the bounty period*
- the bounty award period expires without an explicit award

... then we assume the question owner liked your answer when they accepted it, and it gets the full amount of the bounty **at time of bounty expiration**.

Comment: Great! This is a good addition, people got this wrong frequently.

Comment: Good to hear! If only this had been changed just over a year ago then I would have more rep :) I wish I could accept your answer, but that would be unfair on Lance Roberts....

Comment: Why is it necessary that the answer be *accepted* during the bounty period? If the answer is *posted* during the bounty period, and it solves the question owner's problem (i.e. it is accepted by the owner), why should it lose out on the bounty just because the owner only came back to the site a week later? What would be the harm in awarding the bounty in that case?