# Bounty not awarded automatically — bug?

Tags: bug, bounties

I think [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15461556/) [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15461556/revisions) and [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15461556/timeline) may reveal a bug in the bounty system.

The timeline summary as I see it is:

- Question asked Mar 17
- Answer added Mar 18
- Question edited (extended) and bounty added Mar 20
- Answer edited and accepted Mar 21
- Bounty ends "with no winning answer" Mar 28

This was the only answer to the question.  From [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/150208)

> If the bounty starter accepted an answer during the bounty period, that answer is awarded the bounty.

This appears to be the case here, so I'd expect the bounty to be awarded.  Is this a bug in the bounty system?

I'm not too fussed about the actual bounty here (I'd answered the question before the bounty was offered anyway), it's just that it'd be good to either fix the bug or improve the documentation I guess.

Comment: In case user doesn't award bounty your anser shoud get half of bounty since it have more than 2 upvoye and bounty doesn't  award on accepting answer

Comment: [Here's](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/16067/23) the revision that initially added that text to the docs, I wonder if it was just straight up wrong.  In [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/) Jeff says "all bounties are completely independent of and unrelated to accepting an answer," which kinda subtly suggests that maybe the two aren't related.

Comment: According to [this answer about a similar situation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/54979/137004) that cites a section of the FAQ that's since been removed, accepting doesn't award the bounty.  Looks like the docs are just wrong, though it'd be nice to find more than all this hearsay before changing them.

Comment: @blahdiblah Agreed!  There seems to be quite a bit of conflicting information on this.  Thanks for digging all this up.

Comment: Related: [Bounty Award After Accepted Answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56789)

Answer (score 13):

The bounty was started **after** the answer; logs show:

```
Bounty Start    mar 20 at 10:29
```

The current implementation is explicitly that automatic bounty awards only apply to answers added *after* the bounty. This includes the "an answer was accepted" aspect. I will check internally whether this is intentional, however.

Comment: I was just bitten by this as well; the wording of the FAQ implies that answers given before the bounty period but accepted after, should be awarded the bounty. Furthermore, [Jeff's remarks on the bounty system changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56789/bounty-award-after-accepted-answer/91440#91440) gives a great motivation for *why* the bounty is awarded to the accepted answer, no exception is given for answers that predate the bounty.

Comment: @MarcGravell - Did you check internally or get an answer?

Comment: @Marc Any update on this?

Answer (score 9):

The definitive information in this case is from [the bounty privilege description page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties), which in answer to the question "How do I award the bounty?" notes:

> - You can accept an answer without awarding a bounty to it.

and in discussion of "When does a bounty expire?" clarifies auto-awarding:

> If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period ending, *half* the bounty value will be automatically awarded to the top voted answer posted after the bounty start, provided it has a score of at least 2. If no new answer matches this requirement, no reputation will be awarded at all, and the reputation used on the bounty will be lost forever.

Nothing about acceptance triggering auto-awarding (though there's certainly a case to be made that it should).  The documentation the meta FAQ post on the subject appears to be simply wrong, perhaps a misconception from the earlier setup in which acceptance *did* award bounties.  Caveat wiki-lector.

A related and pertinent question is whether the user who posted the bounty thought that they were awarding it to you by accepting your answer, or whether they were purposely using this somewhat arcane feature of the bounty system.  They would've received notices about the bounty being near-expiry, but might have just assumed they were superfluous.

---

#### BUT WAIT!

The question I linked in a comment above (but didn't read enough of at the time) actually contains [a further note from Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91440/137004) suggesting that the wiki-documentation is correct and that you **should** have been awarded that bounty:

> The implementation has changed a bit to better accommodate careless bounty owners. :)
>
> If ...
>
> - the bounty was started by the question owner
> - the question owner accepts an answer *during the bounty period*
> - the bounty award period expires without an explicit award
>
> ... then we assume the question owner liked your answer when they accepted it, and it gets the full amount of the bounty **at time of bounty expiration**.

I don't know what to believe anymore.

Answer (score 8):

This should be fixed at some point lest the database incur the wrath of people who post multiple answers instead of editing an old one. Stack exchange must not allow the scourge of allowing things which can be worked around anyway to happen.

Comment: _should be_... exactly my thought. Got hit with this the other day which is why I threw a bounty up on this. Apparently it wasn't enough to stir Marc from the grave. Take a bounty