# Automatic bounty reward in 100% amount in certain cases

Tags: feature-request, bounties

I think there are cases when the bounty placer just forgets or can't award the bounty (out of email/internet etc.), but it's perfectly justifiable to award 100% of the bounty automatically for him.

**If the bounty placer accepts an answer within the time-frame of the bounty and doesn't award the bounty in time, award 100% of the bounty automatically to this answer, regardless of the number of upvotes, in the name of the bounty placer (not Community).**

I think that accepting an answer is enough to say - "This is what I wanted!". Then he just keeps the bounty open (once he paid for the attention, why would he give up earlier), but might not be able to come back to it in time.

Comment: This already happens for answers added after the bounty was placed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters are you sure it happens *exactly* like this? I thought it's just 50% and if it has more than 2 upvotes.

Comment: However, if the answer was posted *before* the bounty was placed, even if the answer was accepted during the timeframe, the bounty is **not** auto-awarded to the accepted answer. This is, in my opinion, a bug, but one already reported before.

Comment: Absolutely; from the [Bounty FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work): *If the bounty starter accepted an answer during the bounty period, that answer is awarded the bounty. Answers accepted before the bounty period are not eligible to be awarded the bounty automatically.*

Comment: See [Bounty not awarded automatically — bug?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174070) for the case where the answer was posted before the bounty period.

Comment: Thanks @Martijn! You can post an answer, I will accept. The bug(=feature) should be changed I agree.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If answer was posted before bounty, and bounty reason is not "reward existing answer", then clearly this answer didn't satisfy bounty founder need. So it is not a bug not to give a bounty to it. It's very much desired behaviour.

Comment: @Mołot: I am talking about the OP posting a bounty, then accepting the answer after the bounty started. I've been in that exact situation.

Comment: @Mołot: Did you read the linked bug report at all? In that case the posted answer was edited to meet the bounty requirements.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Accepted answer means "it worked". If bounty reason was "need canonical answer" or "answer with canonical resources" or sth like that, mere fact that answer worked is not enough.

Comment: @Mołot: "reward existing answer" bounties are **rarely**, if ever, auto-awarded. They are posted to award a specific answer manually. And they are usually posted by *someone other than the OP*.

Comment: @Mołot: Then vote on the bug report. How was the answer *here* not helpful to the current question?

Comment: @Mołot: Note that the original bug report makes no mention of that scenario (which I find to be unlikely).

Comment: @MartijnPieters too many @ me in short time. When I'll have time to chat, I'll be on chat. Bye.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *already* happens, provided the answer was posted *after* the bounty period started. Quoting from the [Bounty FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work):

> If the bounty starter accepted an answer during the bounty period, that answer is awarded the bounty. Answers accepted before the bounty period are not eligible to be awarded the bounty automatically.

Note the second half of that sentence though; I consider that behaviour a bug in the current bounty system. See [Bounty not awarded automatically — bug?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174070) for the bug report.